# Trouble making a php colour script

Tags: php

I'm still learning php so please go easy on me.

I've got this small script I've been working on for a project but can't seem to get it to work. I just get an error whenever I try to output it.

error output is : ( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\wamp\www\test.php on line 16

```
     <?php
function pickColour() { 
    //array of colours
    $colours = array(
        'red' => 'E04739',
        'blue' => '0092D6',
        'green' => '2CCA71',
        'orange' => 'EF6521',
        'pink' => 'E73B5B',
        'purple' => '2B5B9C'
        );

    $hash = '#';
    $single = array_rand($colours, 6);
    print_r($single); . "\n"
    echo "$hash .= $single";

    }

    print pickColour();
```

?>

Comment: Which error do you get?

Comment: "can't seem to get it to work" -- you even don't say what is "work"

Comment: `print_r = $single; . "\n"` and `echo $hash .= $single . "\n";` are not valid PHP, so I would expect them to throw errors, which is exactly what it does when I try to run this code. I assume you tried running it too.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans `echo $hash .= $single . "\n";` most definitely *is* valid PHP.

Comment: @meagar, sorry, yes it's valid but completely nonsensical, since $single is an array, not a string =)

Comment: Please stop editing your code. You've asked your question, and now you've changed it so the existing answers are invalid.

Comment: Apologies, ohh I didn't know $single would be turned into an array thought it takes one value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with your script.

1. wrong usage of `echo` and `print_r`
2. the function should return a value
3. wrong usage of `array_rand`

try this:

```
function pickColour() {
    //array of colours
    $colours = array(
        'red' => 'E04739',
        'blue' => '0092D6',
        'green' => '2CCA71',
        'orange' => 'EF6521',
        'pink' => 'E73B5B',
        'purple' => '2B5B9C'
    );

    return '#'.$colours[array_rand($colours)];
}

print pickColour();
```

Comment: does this randomly generate any of the 6 array values on the return.

Comment: yes..it picks one random value. [array-rand](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-rand.php) 1 is the default value for the second param if you don't add one.

Comment: aww okay thanks I understand that php.net wasn't much help in this  thanks alot :)

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues. First, you appear to want a single random array element, but you directed `array_rand()` to return six elements:

```
$single = array_rand($colours, 6);
```

If you want a single element, do:

```
$single = array_rand($colours, 1);
```

or even:

```
$single = array_rand($colours);
```

Next, you have a syntax error here:

```
print_r = $single; . "\n"
```

Since `print_r` is a function it is generally used like this:

```
print_r( $single );
```

Since `array_rand()` returns an array key (and not an array value) you should use the key to retrieve the value from the array:

```
echo $hash .= $colours[$single] . "\n";
```

Finally, you are executing your function like this:

```
print pickColour();
```

Since you are already producing output in your function via `print_r()` and `echo`, the `print` is unneeded. You should use:

```
pickColour();
```

Comment: thanks george that feedback is great.

Answer (score -1):

this is where you have an error:

```
print_r = $single . "\n";
```

change it to

```
print_r($single . "\n");
```

I think what you need is this:

```
function pickColour() { 
//array of colours
$colours = array(
    'red' => 'E04739',
    'blue' => '0092D6',
    'green' => '2CCA71',
    'orange' => 'EF6521',
    'pink' => 'E73B5B',
    'purple' => '2B5B9C'
    );

$random_key = array_rand($colours);
return "#" . $colours[$random_key];
}

print pickColour();
```